# Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surface $z=1-y^2, z=y^2-1, x=0, x=2$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surface $z=1-y^2, z=y^2-1, x=0, x=2$.

I'm still rather new to the whole double integral concept so i was hoping someone could have me out if i did this right.

$$\int_0^2\int_{-1}^1\int_{y^2-1}^{1-y^2}1dzdydx$$ Im not sure if i got this right.

and after all the integration i got to $\frac{16}{3}$

Comment: You probably want $x=2$ instead of $z=2$?

Comment: @thomas yeah sorry about that. Typo. But did i do the integral correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you set up the iterated integral correctly. $z= 1 - y^2$ and $z= y^2 - 1$ are the elliptic parabolas that extend out the $x$ axis, so $ 0\leq x\leq 2$ are the right bounds. Then you have $y$ between $-1$ and $1$ because of the intersection of $z = 1-y^2$ and $z = y^2 = 1$.

Doing this quickly, I also get $16/3$ as the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm really trying to wrap my head around multi variable integration, feel rather daunting. Thanks man!

Comment: @Danxe: No problem. Glad to help. Feel free to upvote and accept.